# My code isn't deleting my php sessions using 'unlink' (debian 10)

Tags: php, cookies, debian-based

So I'm trying to write a script that will limit the amount of users to my web page to one at a time.

So, what i've decided to do was use sessions to find how many connections are being logged, which holds these logs in the following directory /var/lib/php/sessions and look like this for example "sess_bsjg9hgiqgl968sj3fr8okm2o7"

So when a user enters my index.php page, a sess_ file is created in the above directory, and i increment a variable called "visitor" according to how many sess_ files are currently in the folder.

My problem is, when a user closes the tab (or exits my site), their php session (sess_xxyyxx) is not being removed from the folder even though I've gone to the extreme of setting session.gc's to ridiculous values in hopes that the automatic GC (garbage cleaner) will delete the php session files with every refresh of the homepage.

My question is, how can I delete these php sessions from the folder via script if the below code isnt working?

The code is posted below:

```
<?php 


ini_set();
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);



$session_path = session_save_path();

$visitors=0;

$handle = opendir(session_save_path());

session_start();

while (($file = readdir($handle)) != FALSE)
{
    if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")
    {

        if (preg_match("/sess/",$file))
        {
            $visitors++ ;
        }

        unlink($file);
    }
}


?>
```